# built_value has a dependency conflict with flutter_test

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm trying to fetch JSON data using built_value serializer but after setting built_value package in yaml file getting an error like:

> Because built_value_generator >=5.5.3 depends on analyzer ^0.32.1 and
>   every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on analyzer
>   0.31.2-alpha.2, built_value_generator >=5.5.3 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk. So, because tornado_blog_flutter depends on
>   both flutter_test any from sdk and built_value_generator ^5.5.3,
>   version solving failed. pub get failed

How to solve this error?

My yaml file:

```
name: flutter_layout
description: A new Flutter application.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  built_collection: '>=2.0.0 <4.0.0'
  built_value: ^5.5.3

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  json_serializable: ^0.5.0
  build_runner: ^0.9.0
  built_value_generator: ^5.5.3
```

Answer (score 3):

There's some info on this issue [here](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/433). The version of analyzer used by Flutter needs to be upgraded to solve this.

There's an open issue in Flutter to this [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18648) but it doesn't seem to have been done yet.

As a workaround, you could try going back to an earlier version of built_value that doesn't require such a new version of the analyzer.

Comment: dependency_overrides to analyzer: ^0.31.2-alpha.2 solved my problem.

Comment: If dependency override not work then I think downgrading built_value will solve this problem.